# No dejar que se pasen registros ya existentes en mi Jtable

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, bucle-for, condiciones

En mi sistema tengo un JTable con registros de mi base de datos, los cuales se muestran con un Resultset, en mi sistema puedo pasar los datos que yo seleccione del jtable a otro jtable, pero no quiero que se puedan pasar datos con el mismo ID!, este es mi codigo del boton pasar registro al otro jtable:

```
private void botonPasarFilaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
                TableModel model = tablaPorFechas.getModel();
                int indexs[] = tablaPorFechas.getSelectedRows();
                DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) tablaDestino.getModel();
                Object[] row = new Object[17];
        
        
         for (int z = 0; z < model2.getRowCount(); z++) {
          //  String valor = tablaDestino.getValueAt(z, 0).toString().trim();
            if (model.getValueAt(z, 0).equals(model2.getValueAt(z, 0))) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ya se paso ese registro, seleccione registro válido");
                
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < indexs.length; i++) {

                    
                    row[0] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 0);
                    row[1] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 1);
                    row[2] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 2);
                    row[3] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 3);
                    row[4] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 4);
                    row[5] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 5);
                    row[6] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 6);
                    row[7] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 7);
                    row[8] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 8);
                    row[9] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 9);
                    row[10] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 10);
                    row[11] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 11);
                    row[12] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 12);
                    row[13] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 13);
                    row[14] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 14);
                    row[15] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 15);
                    row[16] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 16);

                    model2.addRow(row);
                }

               
            }
        }
```

No logro detectar el problema ya intente de varias maneras, la ultima ha sido esta, si me podrian apoyar mencionandome que estoy haciendo mal porfavor, o algun consejo de que cambiar, saludos, muchas gracias...

Comment: El problema es que estás comparando los valores 1 == 1, 2 == 2... lo que necesitas es usar un segundo bucle dentro del primero para comprar cada elemento de tu primer modelo con cada elemento del segundo!

Comment: y como puedo solucionarlo? el detalle es que no se me ocurre como hacer lo que me comentas, saludos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, lo realice de la siguiente manera en caso de que le sirva a alguien!!, Saludos...

```
void recorrerTableDestino() {

        boolean exists = false;
        String s;
        String p;
        int seleccion;
        seleccion = tablaPorFechas.getSelectedRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < tablaDestino.getRowCount(); i++) {
            s = tablaDestino.getValueAt(i, 9).toString(); //ubicamos el dato en numero de fila

            p = tablaPorFechas.getValueAt(seleccion, 0).toString();

            if ((p).equals(s)) {

                exists = true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ya se regsitro con ese ID: " + tablaPorFechas.getValueAt(seleccion, 0));
                break;

            }
        }
        if (!exists) {

            TableModel model = tablaPorFechas.getModel();
            int indexs[] = tablaPorFechas.getSelectedRows();
            DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) tablaDestino.getModel();
            Object[] row = new Object[10];

            
            for (int i = 0; i < indexs.length; i++) {
                row[0] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 0);
                row[1] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 1);
                row[2] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 2);
                row[3] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 3);
                row[4] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 4);
                row[5] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 5);
                row[6] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 6);
                row[7] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 7);
                row[8] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 8);
                row[9] = model.getValueAt(indexs[i], 9);
                model2.addRow(row);
            }

        }

    }
```